# How do I get the ID from the first table to record the second?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

How do I get the ID from the first table to record the second?
Recalling that the id and generated automatic.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Chamados chamados, InteracoesChamados interacoesChamados)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Chamados.Add(chamados);
            //interacoesChamados.ChamadoId = chamados.ChamadoId;  
            db.InteracoesChamados.Add(interacoesChamados);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(chamados);
    }
```

The comment and exactly what I want to do.
I need  get the code from the first table and save  the second record.
What is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code I assume that IteracoesChamados is a child of Chamados. If so, then set

```
iteracoesChamados.Chamados = chamados
```

The ID will be assigned automatically. Hope this helps.